# Why do I get the "identifier "a" is undefined" in a function where I have a as a parameter?

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, benchmarking, identifier

In the following code:

```
void benchmark(string desc, int(*pf)(int a[50])) {
    printf("\n Benchmark for %s", desc.c_str());
    double tStart = omp_get_wtime();
    int result = pf(a[50]);
    double tFinal = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("\n\t Final result: %d", result);
    printf("\n\t Duration: %f (s)", tFinal - tStart);

int main() {
    int i, b;
    int a[50];
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        b = rand() % 10000 + 1;
        a[i] = b;
    }
    benchmark("Parallel solution without mutex for counting primes", Squential);
    benchmark("Parallel solution with load balancing", Parallel1);
    benchmark("Parallel solution with load balancing", Parallel2);
}
```

On line "int result = pf(a[50]);" the compiler says "identifier "a" is undefined" although I listed it in the parameters list. It may have something to do with the pointer, I'm not used to working with pointers.

Comment: I'm not sure what the cause of your problem is, but `a[50]` in `pf(a[50])` is an error. `a[50]` means "the 51st element of `a`" but `a` only has 50 elements.

Answer (score 3):

This does not have a parameter `a`

```
void benchmark(string desc, int(*pf)(int a[50])) {
```

This has the parameters:

```
* desc:   Type -> string
* pf:     Type -> A function (pointer) that returns int and takes an array of int
```

This is a function pointer type:

```
int (*pf)(int a[50])
      ^^ This is the name of the paramter.

// This is the type
int (*)(int[50])

// This is a pointer to a function that returns an `int` 
// and takes `int[50]` as a parameter.
```

Just to get this copiling do this:

```
int result = pf(a[50]);

// change into this:
int data[50];           // or get this from somewhere else.
int result = pf(data);
```